# Best Practice to inject variables in the grails main layout

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

While reviewing some code in grails, I noticed that at a certain point specific code is reused in every controller and passed to the views to render a view section which can be normally be part of the main layout. The only problem is how to pass those values to the main layout from another point outside the specific controllers.

Any best-practice in dealing with similar cases of passing variables to the main layout?

Comment: take a look at filters: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters

Comment: That should have been an answer, @IgorArtamonov. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro was too short for real answer

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I like OP to explore the content first rather than providing the answer upfront. Fruitful investment of time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a [Filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) for this:

For example:

```
class MyFilters {   

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = { }

            after = { Map model ->
                // add your common data here
                model.commonData = ...          
                return true
            }

            afterView = { Exception e -> }
        }
    }
}
```

The `after` closure gets called after the controller execution but before the view is rendered. You can also be more specific on the filter configuration (`all(controller:'*', action:'*')`). For example you can to exclude certain controllers or something like that.